# How to return location Object when loading file from internal file storage?

Tags: android, object, location, storage, fileinputstream

I am working on some way to store a GPS location within the internal file storage and retrieve it on demand in another method.

As I am new to Android I have tried out several ways and decided to go with the FileOutput-/InputStream as it is more comprehensible to me. I am working with the Android location API(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html).
I know that saving a location Object works technically via writing it to a string and later to bytes, but how can I load a saved file and have the saved location object returned?

My code approach:

```
public void saveCurrentLocation(){ //method works, I can see the saved file in the file explorer
    Location currentLoc = gpsClass.getCurrentLocation(); //method within gpsClass that returns current location
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("SaveLoc", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(currentLoc.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

}

public void loadSavedLocation() {
    Location savedLoc;
    try{
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("SaveLoc")));
        String inputString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(inputString);
    }
        gpsClass.update(??);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I'd like to pass the location Object readout in inputString to "gpsClass.update()" which only takes variables of the type Location. Do I have to make the Object serializable and if yes, how?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not persist your location objects into a SQLite database?
Or something like this:

Save:

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(your object);
os.close();
```

Load:

```
FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
YourClass yourObject = (YourClass) is.readObject();
is.close();
return yourObject;
```

This should get you back on track

Comment: I thought the database option is only useful for a bigger amount of data. In this case I only need to save one location. Please correct if I misunderstood.

Comment: you're right, in this situation a database does not make sense. i thought you want to keep track of these objects.

Comment: What exactly is the "context" in context.openFileOutput for?
Anyway I keep getting java.io.NotSerializableException: android.location.Location ...
How can I make a location Object Serializable?

Comment: you can get a context instance by calling getApplicationContext() in your activity. try saving your Location object as described above.

Comment: Okey, great that you're back on track now.